# JAVA SocketServer with frame

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, frame, serversocket

I'm trying to make Java socket Server, which has frame, where messages are displayed.

But when I run the server from frame constructor, the frame don't become visible.

There is part of my code:

Calling the frame:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                new ServerForm().setVisible(true);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Ship_Server.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    });
```

Creating the server:

```
    public ServerForm() throws IOException {
    initComponents();

    hipServer Server = new hipServer();

}
```

The server constructor:

```
 public ShipServer() throws IOException {
    ServerSocket listener = new ServerSocket(8901);
    System.out.println("Server is Running");
    try {
        while (true) {

          ...
         }
    } finally {
        listener.close();
    }
}
```

Can you suggest something, to run server, and live active frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid having process intensive code in the EDT such as infinite `while` loops.

Have a look at using a [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html). It won't block the `EDT` while waiting for network connections. The `ServerSocket` functionality can be managed in [doInBackground](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#doInBackground%28%29).

Answer (score 0):

You also need to create a thread for the server because of...

```
while(true)
```

...which "never" ends

OR

Display the form (make sure it is visible) before creating the server.